# how can I get the date picker to start select from at least 8 previous days back from this days date?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker

I try to make a date picker where you can only choose dates from 8 days left. If we have the date 09 / 05-2015 you can not select (8,7,6,5,4,3,2) but you can choose the 01 / 05-2015 and go down. How can i make that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".date-picker").datepicker({       
    todayHighlight: true,   
});

$(".date-picker").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date()); //sets the todays date in the input field
$(".date-picker").on("change", function () {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var val = $("label[for='" + id + "']").text();
$("#msg").text(val + " changed");
});

}); // end of document ready
```

Comment: @meskobalazs No its boostrap.js

Comment: Could post a link for the libraryJ AFAIK bootstrap has no datepicker in itself

Comment: @meskobalazs I have added alt the links to the post :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution:

I used the setDate to set the date i want

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker("setDate", "-20d");
```

And used the endDate, so people only can choose dates 20 days back from the current date(todays date).

```
endDate: '-20d'
```

Thanks, for your time!